# HTML to embedded Flash - ExternalInterface callback won't work

Tags: javascript, html, actionscript-3, flash

I'm an HTML novice so I'd really appreciate some help.

I want to communicate between my HTML JS and my embedded SWF. 
I can call my JS functions in my html from Flash which works. But I can't callback from JS to Flash.

I've stripped my code to the minimum but still no success. Here's my code for AS3:

```
package
{
import flash.events.Event; 
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;


public class CFacebook extends Sprite
{
    public function CFacebook()
    {
        init();
    }

    private function init():void
    {
        ExternalInterface.addCallback("myFlashcall",myFlashcall); 
        btn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick1); 
        btn2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick2); 
    }

    public function myFlashcall(str:String):void
    {
        txtDebug.text = "myFlashcall = " + str;
    }

    protected function onClick1(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        ExternalInterface.call("myFBcall1"); 
    }

    protected function onClick2(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        ExternalInterface.call("myFBcall2"); 
    }

}
}
```

This all works - except the callback which is never called. Here's my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Simple Flash Embed</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<script type="text/javascript" >
function myFBcall1()
{
    alert("test1");
}

function myFBcall2()
{
    document.getElementById("SwfFacebook").myFlashcall("IT WORKS");
    alert("test2");
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
data="SwfFacebook.swf"
width="640" height="480">
<param name="movie" value="SwfFacebook.swf" />
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"/>
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"/>
<p>Alternative content -- Can contain any HTML: DIVs, IMGs, etc.</p>
</object>
</body>
</html>
```

My first ALERT shows when I click my first button. The second ALERT is never displayed and my callback function in my SWF is never called.

With Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have an ID of your embeded SWF, so when you make a call:

```
document.getElementById("SwfFacebook").myFlashcall("IT WORKS");
```

nothing happens.

I highly recommend you to use SWFObject embedding tool, it's almost a standard now.
[Link to library](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/)

When you are embedding your swf you just pass an Args array like this:

```
var attributes = {
    id:"flashObject",
    name: "flashObject",
};
```

Or whatever ID or NAME you want and call

```
document.getElementById("flashObject").myFlashcall("IT WORKS");
```

If you are using Flash Builder, Flash Develop or even Intellij IDEA - it automatically generates an index HTML page with swfobject included, so all you'll need to do is to adjust *id* and/or *name* fields. (You should have at least id field not empty);

And btw, I'd recommend you to check your ExternalInterface for availability before adding callbacks or calling external functions:

```
private function init():void
{
    if(ExternalInterface.available)
    {
        ExternalInterface.addCallback("myFlashcall",myFlashcall); 
        btn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick1); 
        btn2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick2); 
    }
}
```

==========
UPDT:

Sometimes (when using default Chrome flash player) it's not working locally and works if you launch your app on any remote server. Try uploading it somewhere and check